# Indexing Alfresco Custom Fields

Tags: alfresco, watson-explorer

With the WEX Foundational Components, is there an out of the box seed/connector to crawl alfresco files that have extra properties/metadata?  I’ve been able to use the alfresco seed/connector and the cmis seed/connector to crawl alfresco files, but it doesn’t index the extra properties.  The extra properties have been added by creating a custom alfresco model.

Comment: Do you know how the crawler works? From what I gather, it requires web script installation on Alfresco side.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8NLW_10.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.connector.alfresco.doc/t_connector-install-webscripts.html

Comment: Interesting.  This link doesn't show up on version 11.0.2 knowledge center.  Will look into this.  Thanks

Comment: What I was thinking is that if we can look at this web script, we can see if it's written in a way to return properties from custom model, too.

Comment: Thanks @Lista.  Your feedback prompted me to look at the setup documentation for the Alfresco and CMIS crawlers and I did miss the fact that in addition to setting up the seed, I had to also add the converter for the specific seed.